# Size of Union changes with unexpected word alignment

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, unions, memory-alignment

I have a struct and a union defined as below

```
struct aa{
   float j;
   char aaa;
   char bbb;
   int bb;
}aaaa; sizeof(aaaa) 12bytes

union utag{
   char bb;
   float kk;
   char *c;
   struct aa lala;
}haha; sizeof(haha) 16bytes
```

My compiler tells me sizeof(aaaa) is 12 and sizeof(haha) is 16.

I do understand that sizeof(aaaa) is 12 because I have a 2byte padding for 4byte word alignment for int bb.

However, I cannot understand why my union haha is 16bytes. I expected it to be 12bytes since struct aa type is the biggest element inside.

What's weird is if I comment out the char *c element inside the union, sizeof(haha) becomes 12bytes as expected.

```
union utag{
   char bb;
   float kk;
   //char *c;
   struct aa lala;
}haha; sizeof(haha) 12bytes
```

I have searched for duplicate questions but no other question manifested the case where an already word-aligned struct (12bytes) adds padding bytes (to make it 16 in this case) or the situation where removing an union element which doesn't affect the size of the union(removing char * which is 8bytes should not change the union size which is already 16bytes by the struct element) actually affects the size.

Comment: `char *` requires 8-byte alignment on a 64-bit system. So the size has to be a multiple of 8.

Comment: @Barmar why would I need an alignment for char * ? it is inside an union whose size is already bigger than 8 bytes

Comment: The size of any type is always a multiple of its alignment requirement. This is needed so that an array of the union will have all its elements aligned properly for that element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the used system `sizeof( char * )` is equal to `8`,

So the address pf the data member `c` should be divisible by `8` for the alignment.

But the data member `lala` can not provide such an alignment then for example objects of the unit type are placed in an array. So the unit is appended with 4 bytes to guarantee such an alignment for the fata member `c`.