# Can a union be larger than the the largest member when the largest member is a primitive type?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, sizeof, unions

Is there a possibility to make the size of a `union` larger than the largest member when the largest member is a integer, floating point type, `_Complex` type, `_Atomic` type, data pointer or function pointer and not a array, `struct` nor `union`*?

For example, can there be (or is there) a system where the following code will print 2 different sizes (assuming printing doesn't fail). If not, is there a other way to generate a `union` that is larger then the largest member even when the largest member is a "primitive type"**?

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(a,b)       ( (a)>(b) ? (a) : (b) )
#define MAX4(a,b,c,d)  MAX( MAX( (a), (b) ), MAX( (c), (d) ) )

union Foo
{
  uintmax_t a;
  long double f;
  void (*fp)(void);
  void *data;
  double complex c;
};

int main(void)
{
  size_t l = MAX4( sizeof(void*), sizeof(void(*)(void)), sizeof(long double), sizeof(uintmax_t) );
  l = MAX( l, sizeof(double complex) );
  printf( "%zu %zu\n", sizeof(union Foo), l );
}
```

It (probably) doesn't change any productive code, it is just for curiosity.

---

Related but not the same question (use of a `struct` inside the `union`): [sizeof union larger than expected. How does type alignment take place here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453881/sizeof-union-larger-than-expected-how-does-type-alignment-take-place-here?noredirect=1&lq=1) [Size of Union changes with unexpected word alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075501/size-of-union-changes-with-unexpected-word-alignment)

*Are there any other classes of types i forgot?

**Is there a proper name for this types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a other way to generate a union that is larger then the largest member even when the largest member is a "primitive type"?

Yes, you can use [`_Alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas):

```cpp
union Foo {
    _Alignas(32) uintmax_t a;
    long double f;
    void (*fp)(void);
    void *data;
    double complex c;
};

//

printf("%zu\n", sizeof(union Foo)); // 32
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GPfhv6vnr)